# filter report and export it in xlsx in aura component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, reporting

i want to filter a report and export it to xlsx when the user click on a button as in lightning component, i use a link like this but it don't work: `String url = baseUrl + '.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Report/'+ reportId+ '/view?fv0=' + userKey + '&xlsx=1&exp=1&enc=UTF-8&isdtp=p1';`
It just filter the report but don't export it. Can someone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following.

```
String url = baseUrl + '.lightning.force.com/servlet/PrintableViewDownloadServlet?isdtp=p1&reportId='+reportId;
```

Comment: i did it but it only donwload the report not filtered it.